# function that allows different outputs dependent on argument values

Tags: bash, function, arguments

With the following function I want to be able to call it
with `nico-usage`  or with a numeric value to print a different string.

Con this be cleaned up or made easier.

```
nico-usage ()
 {

  local docstrg_lang="
 {-V, --version}, {-u, --usage}, {-h, --help}
 -s SCAL, --scale SCAL"

  local docstrg_usage="
 nicolaus -s 0.5 -aq 3"

  usg=$1
  if (( usg == 1 )); then
    echo "$docstrg_lang"
  elif (( usg == 2 )); then
    echo "$docstrg_usage"
  else
    echo "$docstrg_lang"
  fi

 }
```

Comment: A `case` construct would probably be more appropriate here.

Comment: Should checking `$1` be enough or would one also test for `$#` ?

Comment: That depends on your needs. You can dispatch based on `$1` and then check for the existence of `$2` in case of `-s`, `--scale` and the undocumented `-aq`.

Comment: This is only supposed to test for numeric value only, for `nico-usage`, `nico-usage 1`,   `nico-usage 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is how to make it pretty, here is a variant:

```
nico-usage ()
{
   if (( $1 == 2 )) ; then
     echo -e "\nnicolaus -s 0.5 -aq 3"
   else
     echo -e "\n{-V, --version}, {-u, --usage}, {-h, --help} -s SCAL, --scale SCAL"
   fi
}
```